# Run Rsync for multiple files in parallel from 2 different directories and find elapsed time for each file and all files

Tags: shell-script, rsync, for

I have lots of dump files in 2 different directories that need to be uploaded using rsync, I want to run rsync for each dump file simultaneously to save time.

Dump Files:

```
Dir1:

-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir1/NoTDE_CDB_FULL1_01.dmp
-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir1/NoTDE_CDB_FULL1_02.dmp
-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir1/NoTDE_CDB_FULL1_03.dmp
-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir1/NoTDE_CDB_FULL1_04.dmp

Dir2:

-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir2/NoTDE_CDB_FULL2_01.dmp
-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir2/NoTDE_CDB_FULL2_02.dmp
-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir2/NoTDE_CDB_FULL2_03.dmp
-  /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir2/NoTDE_CDB_FULL2_04.dmp
```

Following rsync Command to run for each dumpfile from each directory in the background:

```
rclone sync /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/NoTDE_CDB_FULL_01.dmp NoTDE_Mig1:IC_dbbackup_config_datapump_xxxxxx
```

I managed to get the desired output to run rsync for each file, however, i want to track the start and end time for each file as well as overall elapsed time for the rsync jobs running in background. 
using `time` in for loop will provide only elapsed time for each file, however i also need overall elapsed time of Start and End Time after completing all jobs

````
dumpdir1="/u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir1"

for i in $dumpdir1/*.dmp
do

    echo " time rclone sync  $i NoTDE_Mig1:IC_dbbackup_config_datapump_v00rcfh_iad3p2 &"
done

dumpdir2="/u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir2"

for i in $dumpdir2/*.dmp
do
    echo " time rclone sync $i NoTDE_Mig1:IC_dbbackup_config_datapump_v00rcfh_iad3p2 &"
done```
````

Comment: @user1133275 why would this be a duplicate of a question that explains the differences between `parallel` and `xargs`? Yes, both of those tools could be used here, but the question is about tracking the start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
# `time` will give the total time
time parallel -j0 --joblog mylog rclone sync {} NoTDE_Mig1:IC_dbbackup_config_datapump_v00rcfh_iad3p2 ::: /u05/expdpdump/exppdb/dir{1,2}/*.dmp
# the log contains the time per file
cat mylog
```

Depending on your disks you can get better performance if you do not run all commands in parallel. You limit the number of jobs running in parallel to 5 by replacing `-j0` with `-j5`.

Comment: Thanks Ole, does your suggestion provides "elapsed time" for each file as well as overall elapsed time for all rclone jobs?
I see 'prefixing time' in for loop will provide me elapsed time for each file, however, i am afraid, whether i can track start time and end time of overall.

Comment: I get following error

-bash: parallel: command not found

Comment: @CoolChap007 so install it then!